# How to search for specific value in Json array using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm using a website's `API` to get information. It outputs 100 values.

What is the best practice of searching for a specific value in this array?

The array looks something like this:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "data":
  {
    "array":
    [
      {
        "id":"1","name":"Value1"
      },
      {
        "id":"2","name":"Value2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I try searching for the data using this snippet I found elsewhere, however it does not work:

```
for name in (r.json()['data']['array'][0]['name']):
    if r.json()['data']['array'][0] == s_name:
    ident = r.json()['data']['array'][0]['id']
    name = r.json()['data']['array'][0]['name']
    print (name + ' - ' + ident)
else:
    print ('Nothing was found.')
```

So if I was trying to reference `Value1` how would I do this using `Python`?

Please note: I'm a rookie developer, first time using `Json`, not very experienced with `Python`.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to look at the json librairy for python. r.json() gives a string in a form of a json. You need to `dump` the string to obtain a dict like object

Comment: @Whitefret Assuming `r` is obtained by `request.get()`, `r.json()` returns a Python dictionary.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for the precision. I guess it should work then...

Comment: Alright I look into the documentation. I try to take shortcuts, I have not read any Python/Json documentation I just dove right into it. I have grasped the basics (so I think). However I'm missing out on a lot of things that I should know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure where that piece of code came from but it looks very wrong.

Just looking at the structure you can do something like:

```
for attrs in r.json()['data']['array']:
    if attrs['name'] == s_name:
        ident = attrs['id']
        name = attrs['name']
        print(name, '-', ident)
        break
else:
    print('Nothing found!')
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is a one-liner example for searching:

```
aaa = {
  "success":True,
  "data":
  {
    "array":
    [
      {
        "id":"1","name":"Value1"
      },
      {
        "id":"2","name":"Value2"
      }
    ]
  }
}

[a['name'] for a in aaa['data']['array'] if a['id']=='1']
```

This will return all the found cases, or an empty array if nothing is found

Answer (score 8):

Your code can be simplified a lot:

```
# no need to call `r.json` so many times, can simply save it to a variable
json_data = r.json()
for item in json_data["data"]["array"]:
    if item["name"] == "Value1":
        # do something...
```