# JSON: How to grab value that has key value in an array?

Tags: python

I have a JSON response in python like this:

```
{
   "response" : [
      {
         "section1" : [
            {
               "test1" : "324d",
               "test2" : "433",
            },
            {
               "item" : "trousers",
               "color" : "red",
               "apply" : [ "never", "exclude" ]
            },
            {
               "price" : "277",
               "tax" : "29",
               "apply" : [ "all", "single" ]
            }
         ],
         "site_id" : "38477d",
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I get the `price` from the part that has `apply` value of `all`?

I have been able to manually grab it like this..

```
result['response']['section1'][2]['price']
```

But it changes position in the section each time, how can I search for it instead so that the position does not matter?

UPDATE
To clarify, the `all` will only ever appear once and it will always be in `section1`

Comment: Just make a loop that iterates over them and lookup the keys you're interested in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for specific value in Json array using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115290/how-to-search-for-specific-value-in-json-array-using-python)

Comment: `result['response']['section1'][2]['price']` gives a `TypeError`, it does not pull your desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Search in the list for dicts that have a key called "apply" and then check that key "all" is in that dict:

```
[dic['price'] for dic in test['response'][0]['section1'] if 'apply' in dic and 'all' in dic['apply']][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
sec = result["response"][0]["section1"]
print([x for x in sec if "apply" in x and "all" in x["apply"]][0]["price"])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.